# Search into multidimensional stdClass Object

Tags: php, arrays, search, multidimensional-array, stdclass

I have this stdClass Object:

```
stdClass Object ( 
[summary] => Appuntamenti 
[items] => Array ( 
    [0] => stdClass Object (
        [summary] => Busy 
        [start] => stdClass Object ( 
            [dateTime] => 2016-02-02T17:00:00+01:00 
            [timeZone] => Europe/Rome 
        ) 
        [end] => stdClass Object ( 
            [dateTime] => 2016-02-02T17:30:00+01:00 
            [timeZone] => Europe/Rome 
        ) 
    ) 
) 
)
```

This stdClass Object is the result of a Google Calendar request and can be longer than this.

I'd like to check if there's an event with a specific datetime, for example 
if results contains "Start -> 2016-02-02T17:00:00+01:00" then return true.

I found methods to search in arrays but not in multidimensional stdClass Objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try simple `foreach` at start:

```
$items = $obj->items; // assuming $obj is your initial object
$sample_date = "2016-02-02T17:00:00+01:00";
$hasNeededDate = false;

foreach ($items as $item) {
   if ($item->start->dateTime == $sample_date) {
       $hasNeededDate = true;
       break;
   }
}

var_dump($hasNeededDate);
```